# How to share code on Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey

Hello I made a script for margonem.com (game). The script change some textures and fonts in the game. Some of my friends would like to install my script but I don't know how to share my code in tampermoneky. How can I do it? Like a link to the code with a Install button.